# Configuring Erlang to work with SSL

Tags: ssl, erlang

Erlang version: R13B01

Currently I'm struggling trying to make Erlang work with SSL. The programming part was easy, but now starting the system SSL-enabled is not.

Following the [Erlang SSL documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/ssl_distribution.html):

1 - Made the start_ssl.rel file

```
{release, {"OTP  APN 181 01","R13B01"}, {erts, "5.7.2"},
 [{kernel,"2.13.2"},
  {stdlib,"1.16.2"},
  {sasl,"2.1.6"},
  {os_mon,"2.2.2"},
  {ssl,"3.10.3"}]}.
```

2 - Executed the following command

```
1> systools:make_script("start_ssl",[]).
```

According to the documentation, running the shell would output this (this output is from docs, not mine):

```
$ erl -boot /home/me/ssl/start_ssl
Erlang (BEAM) emulator version 5.0

Eshell V5.0  (abort with ^G)
1> whereis(ssl_server).
<0.32.0>
```

But, I'm receiving this instead:

```
erl -boot start_ssl
Erlang R13B01 (erts-5.7.2) [source] [smp:2:2] [rq:2] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]
1> whereis(ssl_server).
undefined
2>
```

So, for now, the remaining steps are failing too. Sadly, there is no documentation nor forum threads around the web with the same issue.

Any tips?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I can make some comments. First, the boot script needs a .rel extension, not .erl.  Second, BEAM 5.0 is really, really old -- approximately R7B, a decade ago.  Likely the problems you're running into are due to a mismatch between how things used to work so far back and how they now work.  I'd suggest asking on the mailing list to see if someone who knows how things work now can update the docs.

Comment: Sorry, the .erl was an typping error, corrected. The Beam 5.0 is from the documentation, I'm using the one that comes with B13B01

Comment: I know.  I'm saying that that page was apparently last touched when R7 was current, so no wonder what it says no longer works.

Comment: What happens if you start with a normal erl shell and start the applications manually? `application:start(X)` where X is sasl, os_mon and ssl

Comment: application:start(ssl). leads to 'ok' reply, and a bunch of ssl processes are started. But no ssl_server is started at all

Comment: Tested it here. Same result. Since the guide is pretty outdated, there might be no more `ssl_server` process. Did you try simply using SSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after some try and error, I've managed to start the system:

```
application:start(ssl)
```

and passing all certificates when creating the listening socket

```
ssl:listen(Port, ?TCP_OPTIONS ++ [{ip, Host},{verify, 0},
                                       {depth,  0}, 
                                       {cacertfile, Cacertfile}, 
                                       {certfile,   Certfile},
                                       {keyfile,    Keyfile}])
```

It worked :)