# Can anyone post an example of how to enable SSL in Tsung?

Tags: ssl, https, load-testing, tsung

I'm load testing a CouchDB server from another machine using Tsung, and need to establish a secure connection. Unfortunately, I've not been able to find an example of the syntax in the documentation or online...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In tsung.xml:

```
<servers>
    <server host="HOSTNAME_HERE" port="443" type="ssl"></server>
</servers>
```

References from the [current Tsung documentation](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/index.html):

**[6.2. Clients and Server > Basic setup](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual.html#htoc41):**

> Type can be `tcp`, `ssl`, `udp` (for IPv6, use `tcp6`, `ssl6` or `udp6` ; only available in version 1.4.2 and newer) or `websocket` (only available in version 1.5.0 and newer)):

```
<servers>
  <server host="server1" port="80" type="ssl" weight="4"></server>
  <server host="server2" port="80" type="ssl" weight="1"></server>
</servers>
```

**[10. FAQ > Tsung crashes when I start it](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/faq.html#tsung-crashes-when-i-start-it)**

> Does your Erlang system has SSL support enabled?
>   To test it:

```
erl
Eshell V5.2  (abort with ^G)
1> ssl:start().
you should see 'ok'
```

Comment: Thanks Alies. What about credentials? Where are they defined?

Comment: Suppose you have to use Erlang SSL module for this. Look into these articles: [A brief introduction to ssl with Erlang](http://pdincau.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/a-brief-introduction-to-ssl-with-erlang/), [Using SSL for Erlang Distribution](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/ssl_distribution.html), [Using the SSL API](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/using_ssl.html) [Configuring Erlang to work with SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207384/configuring-erlang-to-work-with-ssl).

Comment: Also, ensure you're not using Tsung 1.5.0 -- that version contains [a bug that prevents SSL connections from succeeding](https://support.process-one.net/browse/TSUN-278) and results in an `error_connect_ssl_not_started` error.