# HTTP request gives 302

Tags: ruby, xml, tsung, tsung-recorder

I have setup xml file, I think there ssl certificate issue while I am hitting http request in tsung.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM "/usr/share/tsung/tsung-1.0.dtd">
<tsung loglevel="debug" dumptraffic="true" version="1.0">

  <clients>
    <client host="localhost" maxusers="1" use_controller_vm="true"/>
  </clients>

  <servers>
    <server host="hostname.com" port="443" type="ssl"></server>
  </servers>


  <load>
    <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="1" unit="minute">
      <users arrivalrate="1" unit="second"/>
    </arrivalphase>
  </load>

 <sessions>
  <session name="http_test_1" probability="100" type="ts_http">

      <request subst="true">
        <dyn_variable name="redirect" re="Location: (http://.*)\r"/>
        <http url="/users/sign_in" contents='{&quot;user&quot;: {&quot;email&quot;: &quot;vishal.jagtap+51@zibtek.com&quot;,&quot;password&quot;: &quot;tudip123&quot;}}' content_type='application/json' method="POST" version="1.1">
        </http>
      </request>

    <thinktime random='true' value='27'/>

    <repeat name="redirect_loop" max_repeat="5">
      <request subst="true">
        <dyn_variable name="redirect" re="Location: (http://.*)\r"/>
        <http url="%%_redirect%%" method="GET"></http>
      </request>
      <until var="redirect" eq=""/>
    </repeat>

    <request>
      <http url="/users/edit" method="GET" version="1.1">
        </http>
    </request>

  </session>
 </sessions>

</tsung>
```

in tsung.dump I get 302, how can I hit https request is there any way or any configuration in xml?

please please please help me here! I am stuck from 3 days :(

Comment: can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the ip or just the hostname here not .com.

```
<servers>
    <server host="HOSTNAME_HERE" port="443" type="ssl"></server>
</servers>
```

Refer the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809554/can-anyone-post-an-example-of-how-to-enable-ssl-in-tsung)

Comment: yes, I have tried without .com but it dumps following in tsug.dump file

NewClient:1490008761.822118:1
load:1
NewClient:1490008762.759179:1
load:2